# Anyone know what type of normal form this table is

Tags: sql

So I have this table, but I don't know which normal form it is. I have been looking around for a while now, but can't find the answear. Anyone know what type of normal form this table is? I guess it's not on 3NF or BCNF, but rather 1NF or 2NF.

[Original table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ48U.png)

```
Currency code   Currency name   Date      Currency
EUR             Euro            11.mar       9,701
SEK             Kronor          11.mar      96,95
DKK             Kroner          11.mar     120,12
EUR             Euro            12.mar       9,768
SEK             Kronor          12.mar      96,43
DKK             Kroner          12.mar     119,14
```

Comment: [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-find-the-highest-normal-form-of-a-relation/) might help you

Comment: The key seems to be on columns 1 and 3. And column 2 is dependent on column 1 only. This violates 2nf.

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Answer (score -1):

None of your columns contain embedded lists, so this table is at 1NF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score -1):

BCNF — *The non-key attributes depend on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key* (sometimes with "so help me Codd" appended).

It isn't self-evident from the data, but the currency name does not necessarily determine the current code (think 'dollar', for which there are many sub-species, not all from the USA, but each with its own currency code).  However, the question isn't whether there are other tables that could have different values and different normal forms – the question is about the data in this table.

As it stands, currency code determines currency name and currency name determines currency code.  Further, either columns {1,3} or {2,3} determines column 4.  That means there should be another table with columns currency code and currency name, and one of the columns — probably the currency code — should be designated as the primary key of the new 'currencies' table, and the currency code in the main table will be a foreign key referencing the currency codes table.  This avoids a transitive dependency in the data.

If you look at Wikipedia on [Second Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), you see that it talks about 'non-prime attributes'.  For the data shown, both currency code and currency name are 'prime attributes' — they're part of a candidate key — so the table is is 2NF (but not in 3NF or BCNF).